# Don't break header/footer when making page landscape format

Tags: microsoft-word, format, headers, microsoft-word-2013, landscape

I have a document with a footer with page numbering and a header with some centered text.

*Long story short*: I flipped one page to landscape format.

*Long story long*: I made a forced page break to get a blank page. I then highlighted this page (that is, I highlighted the empty line on this page) and went to the page proporties menu window, clicked on the landscape format button, and chose to apply this setting for the highlighted text only.

*The result*: All that is of course no big deal, and my page is flipped the 90 degrees as wished - but my header and footer **break**! They disappear from this page... and actually also from the next page (which is still upright portrait format), which is weird. And then the header and footer is back on the following pages again, though the **page numbering restarts from 1**.

[image: Image of screenshot]

On this screenshot you can see that the previous and the following pages have headers and footers, but not the flipped one and not the page following the flipped one.

What just happened here?

How can I make the page numbering continue without restarting first of all, and then, how can I keep the header and footer on at least the upright page, that suddenly doesn't have them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go into the footer of your landscape page, and on the ribbon (Design | Navigation), select "Link to Previous". You will get a warning, click "Yes". This should place the footer text back. (You may need to do the same thing for the the header.)

Next, highlight the page number in the footer. Right click and select "Format page numbers". Select "Continue from previous section" radio button.

Check that the sections after the landscape page have not been affected. If they have, repeat the procedure for those sections.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. The "Link to previous" button is already pressed.

Comment: @Steeven Highlight the page number in the footer. Right-click and select "Format page numbers". Select the "Continue from previous section" radio button.

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED: Microsoft Word 2007.

1. Double click the footer.
2. Design Ribbon pops up at top of screen
3. In Design Ribbon, under "Header & Footer" section, select Page Number drop-down  and select "Format Page numbers..."
4. In the Format Page numbers dialog box, ensure radio button under "Page numbering" is set to "Continue from previous section".  Hit OK.

Comment: User is running Word 2013 according to the tags.  Is this fix confirmed to work in Word 2013 as well?

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks! Works still with Word 2016!

Answer (score 3):

The clean way to do it is to delete the page break and replace it with a section break (next page).   At the top of the page after the break, hit "Enter" and insert another section break (next page). Move your cursor back to the top of the page (in between the two breaks), change the orientation to landscape, and insert your chart.  There will be an extra paragraph line on the next page, just delete  it.

Comment: It seems that the header and footer are cleared when I do a section break (before doing anything about landscaping)... If I do a section break before and after the chart, both the page itself and the next page are missing header and footer info.

Comment: Check your header settings and uncheck "different first page" and then it should pull in the header/footer info.  If not, click on "link to previous".

Answer (score 3):

Windows Word 2013:

Somehow Word creates new sections for footers and headers to facilitate single landscape orientations.

To solve your problem you need to tell Word it needs to use the settings from the previous section.

1. Go to Design ribbon, or select footer.
2. Then choose Page number drop-down menu in the ribbon
3. Select Format page numbers, choose continue from previous section

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem and fixed it as follows:

- I noticed that when I opened the header section on the pages that did not have the header and footer it reflected as a **first page header**.
- When I deselected **Different First Page** on this page, the header and footer continued.
- You would need to do this on each page affected

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and this is how I solved it.

My "landscape" page did not have any footer, neither did the page right after it, but the second "portrait" page from the landscape one started from "O".

So I went to the landscape page and selected the same "Page number at the bottom" option as I had originally. When I did this "O" appeared on the landscape page.

Next I double clicked the footer ribbon, highlighted the page number, right-clicked --> format page number, then selected continue from previous section. Once I did this, the break in page numbering was gone.